# How to reuse existing methods of a Rails model class to specify conditions for where method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails model class as shown below:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  def open?
    status != "Completed" || actual_completion_date.blank?
  end

  def completed?
    !open?
  end
end
```

I'd like to define a class-level custom query method that returns all the open projects. Is there a way to reuse the existing `open?` method when definining such a query method, or do I have to rewrite the conditions in the new method like so?

```
def self.open
  where("status != ? or actual_completion_date == ?", "Completed", nil)
end
```

Comment: you can use `scope`

Comment: For reuse existing methods you can use scope . Scope can be defined in class. refer http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope

Answer (score 0):

It is better to get results with sql query. In Rails we use scope which is a syntactic sugar for custom method with sql queries.

Efficient way:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  scope :open, -> { where("status != ? OR actual_completion_date IS NULL", "Completed") }
end
```

Well you can use your `open?` method with [select](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) and achieve same result but it is not at all efficient.

Inefficient way (not recommended):

```
Project.select { |p| p.open? }
```

Answer (score -1):

Re-write your class.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  scope :open, -> { where('status != ? OR actual_completion_date IS NULL', "Completed") }
  scope :completed { where.not(id: completed }

  def open?
    self.in? self.class.open #not recommended if you have a huge table
  end

  def completed?
    self.in? self.class.completed #not recommended if you have a huge table
  end
end
```

The idea is to create a custom query (i.e scope) that support your requirements and then use them inside your methods.

Alternatively, if you still want to use your `open?`, you can still use it in your class method.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  def open?
    status != "Completed" || actual_completion_date.blank?
  end

  def completed?
    !open?
  end

  def self.open
    select { |project| project.open? }
  end
end
```

But the second method returns Ruby Array instead of ActiveRecords::Collections so it can't be chained with other scope.

Comment: Regarding your comment that "self.in?" would not be recommended for a huge table, what would you consider as a huge table in terms of the number of records?

Comment: May I know the purpose of the following statement? scope :completed { where.not(id: completed }